# Please help me understand this amplitude modulation LC oscillator

Tags: oscillator, high-frequency, wave, amplitude-modulation, analog-multiplier

I have a problem understanding the circuit below where the LC oscillator is used to produce the negative cycle wave for the amplitude modulation.

I am having a difficulty in grasping the fact that the oscillator produces the negative cycle. Does the LC get a pulse from the half wave and then this pulse is converted to sine form?

[image]

Secondly, I have my carrier wave given to the signal but with the changing values of the LC my frequency should change accordingly. Should I choose a value of the oscillation equal to the resonant frequency?

Comment: The "LC" is not an oscillator; it's a tuned circuit (sometimes referred to as a tank). The value of the LC doesn't change and, accordingly, the frequency should not change either. The clue is in the phrase "amplitude modulation" and not frequency modulation.

Comment: But how does it generate the nagitive cycle when the rectifier makes it positive

Comment: @Andyaka by. Changing the values I mean that changing the values of the LC changes the results and the output wave. What does the values depend on.?

Comment: There does seem to be some confusion, (and maybe a few things are being mixed up too).  What is the given part of your question - the two frequencies or the two LC components?  Did you calculate the resonant frequency of the existing LC components?  Was it a frequency of interest?

Comment: @Nedd  I meant that how do we select the two LC components value??  Also what's the concept behind using an LC tank here?? I am not getting it conceptually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AM modulation in the simplest way is done like this:
[image]